# How to fasten the While Loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a temp table that conatins more that 10,000 rows. I am trying to have a LIFO matchup based on certain conditions. Added indexes based on the requirement. The query is inside a while loop and it itrates through the loop to finish the matchup process. I am not able to use a cursor since the records may vary from one to another based on the logic.
The process inside the while loop is killingly slow.
Please let me know whether there are any possible ways through that I can avoid the while loop. 
Also please let me know is there any issues creating indexes in a temp table and whether a delete query will change the indexing on a table?

Comment: Your going to need to provide more details; where is the while loop? in the client repeatedly calling the query? what are its loop criteria? what does the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

Joe Celko's book *SQL for Smarties: Advanced SQL Programming* has a section on FIFO and LIFO subsets in Chapter 19.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. The while loop is inside a Stored Procedure. The loop iterates through all the records in the temp table. A flag is there and its value should be 'N', the loop will continue till the value of the flag is 'N'. The script deletes the records from the temp table that ends up in a match. Thus at the end the flag should be set to 'Y' and that will end the loop.

Comment: If you post the TSQL code for your slow stored procedure we can help you optimize it. Perhaps it improved using a ranking function or a recursive CTE.